# Projection of vector into plane

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors, projection

In 3D computer graphics, one needs to represent 3-dimensional objects on a plane screen,
by drawing a given point P at the place where the line from P to the eye meets the screen.
Suppose that the screen is the yz-plane, and the eye is at E : (2, 0, 0).

At what point Q : $(y, z)$ in the yz-plane should one represent the point P : $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$?
(Express y and z in terms of the coordinates of P. Assume that $x_0 < 2$. Why is this
assumption legitimate?

I was trying to:

we know that a  normal vector to the plane is $N  = \langle 1,0,0\rangle$ hence:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{proj}P_N &= \langle x_0,0,0\rangle\\
Q + \mathrm{proj}P_N &= P\\
Q &= P -\mathrm{proj}P_N
\end{align*}$$

hence
$$Q  = \langle 0,y_0,z_0\rangle$$

is this correct?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for angle brackets, not `<` and `>`. Compare `\langle 0,y_o,z_o\rangle` with `<0,y_o,z_0>`: $\langle 0,y_o,z_o\rangle$ vs $<0,y_o,z_o>$.

Comment: This is not correct. For one thing, you are not using the location of the eye at all.

Comment: @GReyes how can I use the location of the eye?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you have described is an orthogonal projection onto the screen.  What you want is a projection through the point $E$.  So you want to solve
$$Q=\lambda E+(1-\lambda)P\tag{1}$$
(This is the parametrization for a line throught two points)
$$Q\cdot \langle 1,0,0\rangle=0$$
(This says $Q$ must lie in plane perpendicular to $x$-axis)

So you get

\begin{align*}
0 = (\lambda E+(1-\lambda)P)\cdot \langle 1,0,0\rangle = 2\lambda +(1-\lambda)P_x
\end{align*}
So $$\lambda=\frac{P_x}{P_x-2}\text{,}$$
and your point is obtained by substituting this value of $\lambda$ into (1) (observe $1-\lambda = \frac{P_x-2}{P_x-2}-\frac{P_x}{P_x-2}=-\frac{2}{P_x-2}$) :

\begin{align*}
Q &=\frac{P_x}{P_x-2}E-\frac{2}{P_x-2}P\\
& = \langle \frac{P_x}{P_x-2}\cdot 2,0,0\rangle-\langle \frac{2}{P_x-2}\cdot P_x,\frac{2}{P_x-2}\cdot P_y, \frac{2}{P_x-2}\cdot P_z\rangle\\
&=\langle 0,\frac{2P_y}{2-P_x},\frac{2P_z}{2-P_x}\rangle
\end{align*}

I will note you could also determine this pretty easily from similar triangles, but perhaps the method I used might be more mechanical and easier to generalize if, for example, you have a plane determined by an arbitrary normal vector.

Comment: can you explain the last step of the computation in detail?

Comment: @KingPalca I elaborated a little more in the original answer

Comment: @M W now I understand, Thank you

Comment: @M W my only question is why you put 0 in the point-to-plane method to get the distance not 0?

Comment: @KingPalca I’m not sure I’m following the question.  I don’t calculate distances at all, and the only use of $0$ came from the equation of the plane, which has normal vector $\langle  1,0,0\rangle$.